# Removing dublicate on PostgreSQL based on 2 columns

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to drop entries based on 2 columns in Postgres. The code for to get the data is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:{}@localhost:5433/stockdata'.format(123))
tickers = ['amzn', 'fb']
for ticker in tickers:
    df = yf.download(tickers=ticker, start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=7), end= datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m", progress = False)
    df['symbol'] = ticker
    df.to_sql('stockdata', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

This will produce a table which looks like this but running the code multiple times will create duplicates:

```
    Datetime    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume  symbol
0   2022-03-28 13:30:00+00:00   3299.500000     3318.000000     3298.000000     3311.023438     3311.023438     133898  amzn
1   2022-03-28 13:35:00+00:00   3313.000000     3344.479980     3313.000000     3339.060059     3339.060059     104565  amzn
2   2022-03-28 13:40:00+00:00   3348.500000     3365.989990     3342.344482     3354.570068     3354.570068     126489  amzn
3   2022-03-28 13:45:00+00:00   3356.000000     3356.000000     3340.000000     3340.000000     3340.000000     70492   amzn
4   2022-03-28 13:50:00+00:00   3338.500000     3348.669922     3337.385010     3347.584961     3347.584961     64041   amzn
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1559    2022-04-01 19:40:00+00:00   223.380005  223.660004  223.039993  223.110001  223.110001  258564  fb
1560    2022-04-01 19:45:00+00:00   223.080002  223.589996  223.059998  223.570007  223.570007  246820  fb
1561    2022-04-01 19:50:00+00:00   223.600006  224.610001  223.600006  224.485001  224.485001  469905  fb
1562    2022-04-01 19:55:00+00:00   224.460007  224.940002  224.460007  224.869995  224.869995  651629  fb
1563    2022-04-01 20:00:00+00:00   224.850006  224.850006  224.850006  224.850006  224.850006  0   fb

1564 rows × 8 columns
```

There is no primary key in the database(I don't have any control over that). Thus the objective is to make sure that `Datetime` is unique to the `Symbol`. For example FB can only have 1 instance of unique `Datetime` entry.  The data is on a `5m` resolution. How can I `group` `by` on `Datetime` and `Symbol` and remove duplicate  entry based on column `Datetime`

I was trying to do this earlier:

```
query = """delete from stockdata s
using 
(SELECT "Datetime" , max(ctid) as max_ctid from stockdata group by "Datetime") t
where s.ctid<>t.max_ctid
and s."Datetime"=t."Datetime";"""
```

But this was looking at just `Datetime` duplicates and not based on grouping `Symbol` symbol column as well.

To get the a list of duplicate:

```
SELECT "symbol", "Datetime", COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM stockdata
GROUP BY "symbol", "Datetime"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

How can I remove all duplicates and keep 1. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This contradicts what you said in your previous question [duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710890/removing-duplicatated-rows-in-postgresql). In fact I specifically asked if there was a stock symbol involved and you said: 'This data is not a stock data (i am using it as a troubleshoot example) but from yokogawa datalogger.'.  Makes it hard to believe what you are telling us.

Comment: Yes you did. I was earlier under the impression that one 1 record per date is needed. I told you best of what I understood was the issue.  I am sure this is it now. Please help!

Comment: That does not answer the question as to whether you are working with stock market data or sensor data from a data logger?

Comment: Its sensor data. But I dont have that data to share. I need to make do with some other data, thus using stock market

Comment: Then add that information to your question, that you are working with proxy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised query. Test before using in production:

```
query = """delete from stockdata s
using 
(SELECT "symbol", "Datetime" , max(ctid) as max_ctid from stockdata group by "symbol","Datetime") t
where s.ctid <> t.max_ctid
and s."Datetime" = t."Datetime"
and s."Symbol" = t."Symbol";"""
```

Also from my comments on previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710890/removing-duplicatated-rows-in-postgresql), it would be better to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the receiving table to prevent duplicates from be entered in the first place.

Comment: Could I please ask for a follow up to your above answer. When I run the above code I get the following message `DELETE 2116` however when I check the size of the table with `\dt+` it does not reduce. Although when i try to search for duplicate with the code in question, there are no duplicates found. So why is the table size not reducing?

Comment: Because it has not been `VACUUM`ed yet. Does `count()` on the table show the  2116 rows gone? Is the code being run using `psycopg2` and are you searching for duplicates in the same `psycopg` session? If so did you remember to do a `commit()` before you went into `psql` and did `\dt+`?